# Prevent background download from stopping in android app when screen rotated

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity, android-lifecycle

So I have a download button in my application which starts an ASyncTask to download a binary file. When I rotate the screen it stops the download obviously because the activity is destroyed.

Would there be a way to stop the download from being killed or would I just have to save the state and then restart the download when and if the screen is rotated?

Thanks

Comment: Several issues here.  You likely want to indicate in your Manifest that you handle orientation changes.  And for tasks which take meaningful amounts of time during which the user might *want* to do something else without losing progress, you may want to not only use a threading mechanism but a background service.   For downloading in particular, review the DownloadManager docs at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html before deciding if you want to roll your own implementation.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm not sure, that DownloadManager is good idea. As I know DownloadManager is used for downloading "public" files, files which you can access from other apps. It will be shown in Downloads app. If Joiya550 wants to download file for internally usage, it's not good idea.

Comment: Check out this [post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) and bookmark it, lots of useful tutorials there.

Comment: I download a file on an aws server just for the sake of testing the transfer rate of the connection on my phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTask which downloading really doesn't stop. But when you rotate phone it recreating and callback trying to update old activity. That's why you don't see result.
To avoid this you need to user loaders (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html). Look at AsyncTaskLoader, it similar to AsyncTask, but provide mechanism to avoiding your problem

Comment: But would I have to change the whole Activity to implement a LoadManager? I created a subclass of LoadManager and then subclassed ASyncTaskLoader but I'm not sure if that's the right way to do it.

Comment: No, you don't need to implement loader manager. You need to call getLoaderManager() method in your activity (or fragment). In that method you need to pass loader id, integer to identify this loader, bundle with params and loaderCallbacks. You must implement loaderCallback and in onCreateLoader return instance of your implementation of AsyncTaskLoader. There is an example at the bottom of page that I posted in answer.